# Proving surjectivity in the third isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a few questions about groups. I asked these questions in a previous post but, am splitting it up into a few different posts from a suggestion given in the previous post.

When proving the third isomorphism theorem, a map $\varphi: G/K \rightarrow G/H$ defined by $gK \mapsto gH$ is present. My main question is, how do you prove that this is surjective? Of course you could say $gH = \varphi(gK)$ for some $gH \in G/H$ but, we don't know for sure what the representative of this coset is. For example, if you were given the set $\{...,-5,-2,1,4,...\}$ but not given the name of the set $1+3\mathbb{Z}$, we don't know what the representative of this coset is. So, can we really say that $gH = \varphi(gK)$ is valid?

Comment: $gH$ is the image of $gK$.

Comment: How would you formulate this in a proof? Would you say, given $gH \in G/H$, $\phi(gK) = gH$? My problem is that, we don't know for sure what $g$ is because every coset has multiple possible representatives

Answer (score 2):

$1+3\Bbb Z$ is not "the" name of that coset. It is one of its names; other names for the exact same coset are $-5+3\Bbb Z$ and $4+3\Bbb Z$ and $-2+3\Bbb Z$.... Given any $g\in\{\dots,-5,-2,1,4,\dots\}$, it is the case that $g+3\Bbb Z$ is a name for that coset. That's why saying that $gH=\phi(gK)$ is valid: $gH$ is an accurate name for that coset, regardless of whether there's a different name that we humans find more natural. (This exact point is also a critique of thinking that $1$ is "the" representative of the coset $1+3\Bbb Z$. Any element of that coset is a representative of the coset.)

Comment: Thank you. But my question is that, this could mean that $gH = \phi(g_1K)$ for some different $g_1$ such that $g^{-1}g \in K$. That's my main problem

Comment: And then $g_1K=gK\ldots$

Comment: Even if $g_1K \ne gK$, that doesn't matter, because surjectivity only requires the existence of a preimage, not a unique preimage.